# I have 2 Columns of text, Should I use different vectorizer and Embeddings for each or just one?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow, text-generation

I have a dataset with two input columns as text. Should I use same textvectorizer in both columns or different ones?

I am asking this because. `columns a` has average length as 500 words, while `column b` has average length of 50 words.

what and How would you do it?

Comment: It depends what these columns represent and what is the goal: if they have a really different role with respect to the target class, then it might makes sense to represent them separately, but this has a disadvantage that it generates more features.

Comment: `column a`  is a paragraph and  `column b` is a question from paragraph.

Comment: What are you trying to predict?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that the two texts are related, choose the same text vectorizer.

The average length of each text instance has almost no impact on choosing a text vectorizer.